# Execute a command if F+J keys are pressed

Tags: xmodmap, xbindkeys, xcape

What would I need to do if I wanted to execute: `chromium &` by pressing <kbd>F</kbd>+<kbd>J</kbd> ?

*Preferred requirements:*

- Globally accessible across Desktop Environment
- Independent of terminal focus or not
- Without using modifier hack in other words if <kbd>F</kbd> **OR** <kbd>J</kbd> is held down, treat it as <kbd>ALT</kbd> or <kbd>SUPER</kbd> key

Answer (score 0):

You mention [xbindkeys](https://linux.die.net/man/1/xbindkeys) in the question tags. Use that.

In `$HOME/.xbindkeysrc` add something like:

```
“chromium &”
f + j
```

Comment: Thanks, but original functionality of J key is now launching chromium every time I press it... leading me to believe something is "stuck"